# How to align Title placement in Tabs using bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I'm using a `<a href>` tag for a title for my last tab.  It gets placed at the bottom on the tab instead of the top like the others.  Is there a way to fix this with css?

here's the html code:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
<li class="active"><a href="#tabs-first"  role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Boat<br>Times   </a></li>
<li>               <a href="#tabs-second" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">General         </a></li>
<li>               <a href="#tabs-third " role="tab" data-toggle="tab">What To<br>Bring</a></li>
<li>               <a href="#tabs-fourth" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">LINKS           </a></li>
<li>               <a href="#tabs-fifth " role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><a href="crew.php">Crew</a></a></li>
</ul>
```

and here's a js fiddle: [TAB TITLES](https://jsfiddle.net/rss81/42xL652s/)

Comment: What's the purpose in nested a tags?

Comment: I'm just using the last tab to redirect to another page, so when you click on that tab instead of taking you to a <div> it takes you to another page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nested anchor tags is what is creating the problem there but if you want to make it work with nested anchor tags then try this:

```
<li>
    <a href="#tabs-fifth " role="tab" data-toggle="tab" style="padding:0;">
        <a href="crew.php">Crew</a>
    </a>
</li>
```

All i have done is added the inline CSS.
Hope this helps.

Comment: also need to set border to 0

Answer (score 0):

set border and padding to 0 on outer